# Force Unwrap Swift Int Row Value

Tags: swift

I am trying to get the value from a row, turn it into a string and then check to see if that string is in an array. So far I have this:

```
 let row: IntRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "devicefield")

        let stringvalue = String(describing: row?.value)

        if (row?.value) != nil

        {
            if tableDevices.contains("\(stringvalue)")

            {
                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "filterData"), object: nil)
            }

            else

            {
                SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: "\(stringvalue) does not exist at your facility")

                return
            }

        }
```

But for some reason it keeps printing out my variable `stringvalue` as an optional.

Comment: No, `stringvalue` is not an optional, but it is literally `"Optional(yourIntRow)"`.

Comment: 1- Do not use `String(describing:)`. 2- Do not use it with an Optional! 3- Do not use it at all...

Comment: I seriously have no idea why all of a sudden in every second SO question somebody is misusing `String(describing:)` and running into problems.

Comment: @luk2302 It's because Xcode prompts with that as the solution.

Comment: @Mozahler that only shifts the question: why do some many people blindly trust their IDE / Xcode? I do not expect an answer, I am just amazed...

Comment: I understand, but swift changes so rapidly that it can be hard to keep up. Sometimes you need to "get it to compile", and forget to go back and understand the problem. I know it happens to me.

Comment: Not sure why I was down voted on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

row?.value is an optional. That's pretty clear since you see the "?". So the print command you are using is simply printing out that it is an optional.  The string isn't optional, the variable is.  You can get a new variable like this:

```
if let printableRowNumberAsInt = row?.value {
// do your stuff like...
   print("\(printableRowNumberAsInt)")
}
```